# Bootstrap Modal and MVC Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, bootstrap-modal

I have a KendoUI Grid that returns some data, I have a button inside a '.clienttemplate' that is bound to the data Id.  When you click on that link it uses the Bootstrap 3 modal to display a partial view.  The problem is that despite the id's all being different I always get the same results back (usually the first id you click on whent he page loads)

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo_Range_Test.ViewModels.VesselViewModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(c => c.owner_company);           
      columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_name);
      columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_type);                           
      columns.Bound(c => c.fixture_stop);
      columns.Bound(c => c.fixture_location);
      columns.Bound(c => c.fixture_note);
      columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_status);
      columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(180);
     columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_idx)
           .ClientTemplate(
           "<a data-identity='#=vessel_idx#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='\\#myModal' href='" + Url.Action("VesselModal", "BrokerHome") + "/#=vessel_idx #'" + ">Vessel</a>");
  }
  )
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
  .Pageable()
  .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
      .Ajax()
      .PageSize(40)
      .Model(model =>
          {
              model.Id(p => p.vessel_idx);
          })
      .Read(read => read.Action("vessels_Read", "BrokerHome"))
      .Update(update => update.Action("vessels_Update", "BrokerHome"))
  )
```

)

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult VesselModal(int? id)                       
    {
        var vessel = db.tbl_vessels.Find(id.Value);
        var vm = Mapper.Map<VesselViewModel>(vessel);
        return PartialView("_VesselDetails", vm);
    }
```

What I noticed was that when I apply some breakpoints this controller method only get's called once and never again which is why the results are always the same in the modal.  What can I do to ensure it makes a fresh call to the method on every item that's click on or should I do this modal another way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Yanayaya Try separating that anchor out and handling the modal with ajax + jQuery?

Razor

```
...
columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_idx)
           .ClientTemplate(
           "<a class='getVesselModal' data-identity='#=vessel_idx#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='\\#myModal'>Vessel</a>");
...
```

Script

```
            $(function () {
                $(document).on('click', '.getVesselModal', function () {
                    this.blur();

                    var myID = $(this).data('identity');

                    //I normally use this line..
                    //$('#myModal').html("");

                    $('#myModal').replaceWith($('#myModal').clone());

                    $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("VesselModal", "BrokerHome")?id=' + myID,
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#myModal').append(response);
                            $('#myModal').modal();
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert("Failure");
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried those already.  You can access the show and hide events.  I tried adding $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) { $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }) }) but it didn't help.  You get the same problem.

Comment: Try adding the two lines I put in my answer before the ajaxSetup you mention

Comment: Thanks, so I added those lines, they only let you add a modal once.  Then it won't open again.  I removed the $('#myModal').html(""); and left the clone line which lets you open a couple of data items then starts showing the same data again.  It feels like it's almost there.

Comment: Could try separating that anchor out a bit and handle it with ajax in a script. I changed my answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.  On the hiddent event triggering removeData seemed to work the best.  I now get the expected results.

Here is the code

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
   $(this).removeData('bs.modal');                                     
})
```

Comment: Good job. Much easier.